# Accessing values of nested dictionaries

Tags: variables, properties, ansible

I'm working some separate tasks for automating VM deployments through tower.
Basically I just need a quick run down on how to gather/use the various properties of a registered return from a task.
I've got this.

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Gather disk info from virtual machine using name
    vmware_guest_disk_info:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ esxipassword }}"
      datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
      name: "{{ fqdn }}"
    register: disk_info
  - debug:
      var: disk_info
```

This spits out the information I want. But, for the life of me I can't figure out how to select a single property. can someone tell me how to do that (particularly for the `backing_filename`) property?
I mean in powershell it would just be `disk_info.backing_filename` or something like `backing = $disk_info | select -expandproperty backing_filename`. Just looking for something like the equivalent of that.

Snip of output

```json
{
    "disk_info": {
        "guest_disk_info": {
            "0": {
                "key": 2000,
                "label": "Hard disk 1",
                "summary": "104,857,600 KB",
                "backing_filename": "[datastorex] vmname/vmname.vmdk",
```

Comment: `disk_info.guest_disk_info.0.backing_filename`, in your example.

Comment: But it is unclear if you do have only one disk, or multiple, and then how the data structure change. And also, what do you need it to be outputed like? A list, a comma separated string, anything else?

Comment: I appreciate the help. That makes sense as if it's an array (comparing to pshell again).

Comment: Didn't mean to submit that already. I appreciate the help. That makes sense as if it's an array (comparing to pshell again). However, I'm still not getting what I expect. Just errors. FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element.         This is the code (ish).. tried with just the "var" and the msg.. both give similar errors. register: disk_info
      - debug:
          var: "{{ disk_info.guest_disk_info.0.backing_filename }}"
          #msg: The backing is {{ disk_info.guest_disk_info.0.backing_filename }}

Comment: and in this particular case I'm always going to have 1 disk, but I'm mainly just trying to figure out how to work with these return arrays.

Comment: `disk_info.guest_disk_info['0'].backing_filename`, possibly

Comment: I was finally able to get it to output what I was looking for by doing - debug: var=disk_info['guest_disk_info']['0']['backing_filename']. So at least that's a little progress. I appreciate it! I know this is super easy stuff for most. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, this one is not as simple as it looks, because your dictionary has a key being a **string** `0`, but, would you be doing `disk_info.guest_disk_info.0.backing_filename` you would try to access an element `0`, so a list, and not a dictionary key `'0'`.

Here would be an example playbook solving your issue:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        var: disk_info.guest_disk_info['0'].backing_filename
      vars: 
        disk_info:
          guest_disk_info:
            '0':
              key: 2000
              label: Hard disk 1
              summary: 104,857,600 KB
              backing_filename: "[datastorex] vmname/vmname.vmdk"
```

That gives:

```json
{
    "disk_info.guest_disk_info['0'].backing_filename": "[datastorex] vmname/vmname.vmdk"
}
```

---

While this works also, you would see that the YAML is representing a totally different structure, also including a list, and not only multiple nested dictionaries:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        var: disk_info.guest_disk_info.0.backing_filename
      vars: 
        disk_info:
          guest_disk_info:
            - key: 2000
              label: Hard disk 1
              summary: 104,857,600 KB
              backing_filename: "[datastorex] vmname/vmname.vmdk"
```

To give you an equivalent in JSON, since you seems to have issue understanding the YAML constructions, your output is

```json
{
  "disk_info": {
    "guest_disk_info": {
      "0": {
        "backing_filename": "[datastorex] vmname/vmname.vmdk"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That would be accessible via `disk_info.guest_disk_info['0'].backing_filename`.
While

```json
{
  "disk_info": {
    "guest_disk_info": [
      {
        "backing_filename": "[datastorex] vmname/vmname.vmdk"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Would be accessible via `disk_info.guest_disk_info.0.backing_filename`